# Restrict _.reduce of underscorejs to use only 2 decimals

Tags: underscore.js

I'm using underscorejs to add up some values. Even though my input values (value.Amount) contain only 2 decimal places, the sum returned by _.reduce is something like 413.6899999995. Heres my code

```
$scope.Total = _.reduce(data, function(memo, value) {
                    return memo + value.Amount;
                }, 0);
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the absolute best way to do it, but it will keep the answer to two digits:

```
$scope.Total = parseFloat(($scope.Total).toFixed(2));
```

Returns 413.69 for 413.6899999995 in Chrome for me